# How to mock a set of strings in spock

Tags: spock

I want to mock a set of strings using spock.
i will pass this mock object as a argument to a method.

Can someone give me the syntax for that ?

i have tried ,
  def set = Mock(Set) but it does not mock a set of strings .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bad question :)   This works ,

def setStrings = Mock(_ as Set)

Comment: `def set = Mock(Set)` is correct; `Mock(_ as Set)` isn't (and will fail with an exception). You'd have to clarify what exactly you mean by "it does not mock a set of strings". Typically you wouldn't mock a collection but use a real one.

Comment: Why would you mock a set of strings?

Comment: Please either delete your question or select your own answer as the correct one. I recommend the former.